# Interpolating Scattered Data from a Volume that has Empty Space

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have 3d data produced from mesh points. The structure that was meshed is complex enough that interpolation using griddata is lacking. Specifically, there are regions without data points which are being given values by griddata that are not the fill_value. I need these hollow regions to have the value of 0.0, which I set fill_value to.

A simplified version of this is illustrated below:
[image: cylinider intersecting data region]

The area occupied by the cylinder has no data points but the rest of the cube volume does. There will be data points from interpolation inside the cylinder but I need them to be zero.

Below is a slice parallel to the xy plane of the actual interpolated data with a black oval that approximates the edge 'cylinder'. The red an blue 'bleed' in to the void after interpolation. The fill value of 0.0 can be seen in the upper left corner:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve the goal of setting those values to 0.0? Note that the 'cylinder' is not of constant shape.

I thought about going z layer by z layer and finding a polygon that gives the cylinder shape and then setting points inside the polygon to zero.

I also thought about partitioning the volume so a portion of the cylinder ends up in corners of the partion (for each z layer) and hoping that the interpolator would not try to extrapolate into the void region.

The first option seems better, but I would like to know if Python provides some sort of functionality which would work better.

EDIT: Here are some actual points from the data set:

[image]

The z scale is much smaller than x or y. You can see that the regions I'm interested in are pretty well defined. But, again, how do I identify them for the purposes of setting grid points to 0.0?