# Finding edge from 2d points Python

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection, convex-hull, scikits

I have several 2d sets of scattered data that I would like to find the edges of. Some edges may be open lines, others may be polygons.

For example, here is one plot that has an open edge that I would like to be able to keep. I would actually like to create a polygon from the open edges so I can use `point_in_poly` to check if another point lies inside. The points that would close the polygon are the boundaries of my plot area, btw.
[image]

[image]

Any ideas on where to get started?

**EDIT:**

Here is what I have already tried:

1. KernelDensity from sklearn. The edges point density varies significantly enough to not be entirely distinguishable from the bulk of the points.

   ```
   kde = KernelDensity()  
   kde.fit(my_data)  
   dens = np.exp(kde.score_samples(ds))  
   dmax = dens.max()  
   dens_mask = (0.4 * dmax < dens) & (dens < 0.8 * dmax)  
   ax.scatter(ds[dens_mask, 0], ds[dens_mask, 1], ds[dens_mask, 2],  
   c=dens[dens_mask], depthshade=False, marker='o', edgecolors='none')
   ```

[image]

Incidentally, the 'gap' in the left side of the color plot is the same one that is in the black and white plot above. I also am pretty sure that I could be using KDE better. For example, I would like to get the density for a much smaller volume, more like using radius_neighbors from sklearn's `NearestNeighbors()`

2. ConvexHull from scipy. I tried removing points from semi-random data (for practice) while still keeping a point of interest (here, 0,0) inside the convex set. This wasn't terribly effective. I had no sophisticated way of exlcuding points from an iteration and only removed the ones that were used in the last convex hull. This code and accompanying image shows the first and last hull made while keeping the point of interest in the set.

   ```
   hull = ConvexHull(pts)
   contains = True
   while contains:

       temp_pts = np.delete(pts, hull.vertices, 0)
       temp_hull = ConvexHull(temp_pts)
       tp = path.Path(np.hstack((temp_pts[temp_hull.vertices, 0][np.newaxis].T,
       temp_pts[temp_hull.vertices, 1][np.newaxis].T)))
   if not tp.contains_point([0, 0]):
       contains = False
       hull = ConvexHull(pts)
       plt.plot(pts[hull.vertices, 0], pts[hull.vertices, 1])
   else:
       pts = temp_pts

   plt.plot(pts[hull.vertices, 0], pts[hull.vertices, 1], 'r-')
   plt.show()
   ```

[image]

Ideally the goal for convex hull would be to maximize the area inside the hull while keeping **only** the point of interest inside the set but I haven't been able to code this.

3. KMeans() from sklearn.cluster. Using n=3 clusters I tried just run the class with default settings and got three horizontal groups of points. I haven't learned how to train the data to recognize points that form edges.

Here is a piece of the model where the data points are coming from. The solid areas contain points while the voids do not.

[image]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511114/strategy-for-isolating-3d-data-points), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357699/interpolating-scattered-data-from-a-volume-that-has-empty-space) are some other questions I have asked that show some more of what I have been looking at.

Comment: Try the image-processing tag; they handle this sort of discovery all the time.  :-)

Comment: What you are trying to do is find the 'convex hull' of a set of points. There are a number of [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Algorithms) you can use to do this.

Comment: Looks like there is some structure in your plots.  Is it possible to exploit that?  Or is this a non-characteristic example?  Here it looks like you are interested only in the left most edge.  Is that general?

Comment: Scipy can find convex hulls for you: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull

Comment: Yeah but that line isn't a convex hull.  The OP wants something that goes near to the points even though their "edge" is not convex.

Comment: @strubbly I do have a SolidWorks model but I don't think there is a way to use the information. All: next I think I will try selecting a few point along some of the curves of interest and then iteratively get their nearest neighbors and add points such that the area of the hull is greater, or move on if it's smaller or not convex. I would use the `add_points()` method from scipy's ConvexHull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to do this in a roundabout way.

I used images of slices of the model in the xy plane generated from SolidWorks to distinguish the areas of interest.

[image: Slice of model]

If you see them, there are points in the corners of the picture that I placed in the model for reference at known distances. These points allowed me to determine the number of pixels per millimeter. From there, I mapped the points in my analysis set to pixels and checked the color of the pixel. If the pixel is white it is masked.

```
def mask_z_level(xi, yi, msk_img, x0=-14.3887, y0=5.564):
    im = plt.imread(msk_img)
    msk = np.zeros(xi.shape, dtype='bool')

    pxmm = np.zeros((3, 2))
    p = 0

    for row in range(im.shape[0]):
        for col in range(im.shape[1]):
            if tuple(im[row, col]) == (1., 0., 0.):
                pxmm[p] = (row, col)
                p += 1

    pxx = pxmm[1, 1] / 5.5
    pxy = pxmm[2, 0] / 6.5
    print(pxx, pxy)

    for j in range(xi.shape[1]):
        for i in range(xi.shape[0]):
            x, y = xi[i, j], yi[i, j]
            dx, dy = x - x0, y - y0
            dpx = np.round(dx * pxx).astype('int')
            dpy = -np.round(dy * pxy).astype('int')

            if tuple(im[dpy, dpx]) == (1., 1., 1.):
                msk[i, j] = True

    return msk
```

Here is a plot showing the effects of the masking:
[image: Masked and regular images]

I am still fine tuning the borders but I have a very manageable task now that the mask is in largely complete. The reason being is that some mask points are incorrect resulting in banding.

[image: Bands in integrated data]